# PHP Zend Framework Killing sessions amongst all browsers when logging off

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-session

I can login to my application using firefox and google chrome. When I click logout of google chrome, it goes back to the login screen. However, the user is still logged into firefox. How do I remove the sessions from both firefox and google chrome when I log a user out of one of the browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: you can save each sessionid in db table, then you can find userid and terminate all session.

Comment: That works! Can you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to store each session_id with user_id in db table, for example:

```
table active_session
id: primary key
user_id: int 11
session_id: varchar(50)
login_time: timestamp
```

then if you want to terminate one session, you can search for user_id using session_id, then, delete all other sessions from the table.

Comment: How do I add a userid to the session table and have it recognized by zends savehandler?

Comment: why you go for direction, user_id should be exist in user table